# Ploblem of This code(show pr0cess) [ps Linux]

Tags: bash

This code show user's process load (%cpu)

```
ps aux | awk 'NR!=1{print $1}' | sort | uniq | awk '{print "ps aux | grep "$1}' | awk '{printf $0; printf " | awk"; printf "{sum +="; print "$3}" }' | sed "s/{/ '{/g" | sed "s/3}/3} END {print \$1,sum}'/g" > 0.out

chmod 755 0.out

bash 0.out
```

This Code show same user in some OS(UBUNTU) example:
root 11.5
root 0
root 0
root 1.8
root 1.3
root 0
root 1.1

but show different user(uniq) on some OS  example2:
root 11.5
daemon 0
syslog 0 ....

How can i write for example2 only.i want diff3rent user's %cpu.

Comment: A couple of observations.  `sort | uniq` can be simplified to `sort -u`.  The `printf` calls in your awk code should almost certainly be `print`; `printf` will misbehave if the string happens to contain any `'%'` characters.  Your code would be much easier to read if you split it across multiple lines, one per command; use `\\` characters as continuation lines.  I'm sure there's a much simpler way to do what you're doing; I'll take a look later, or someone else will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all that with:

```
ps ahx -o "%U %C" | awk '
  {cpu[$1] += $2} 
  END {for (user in cpu) {print user, cpu[user]}}
'
```